# Access Angular directive/component instances in Protractor test

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I have an Angular application. In Angular unit tests (karma / jasmine) I can access component instances and directives via `ComponentFixture` / `DebugElement`.

Is that somehow also possible when running an e2e test via Protractor?

Comment: No, the whole point of E2E tests is that you interact with the application as a user would, through the browser.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you need this for. There are things like `ng.probe` or `getDebugNode` but it's not clear what is your case. The term 'e2e' can refer to real end-to-end/acceptance tests or (erroneously) any kind of Protractor tests - integration, functional, whatever.

Comment: I'm aware, that I should not do that in a "real" e2e test. In my case, I just want to use a protractor test as a "vehicle" to extract some data from my app.

Comment: I will try `ng.probe` and `getDebugNode`, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @estus Please provide the `ng.probe`hint as answer, so I can accept it. It was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked it. Provided the answer, in case if somebody else will need it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getDebugNode(domElement)`](https://angular.io/api/core/getDebugNode) can be used to get [debug element](https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement) inside the application, because it should be imported from `@angular/core`.

`ng.probe(domElement)` is global and can be used to get debug element outside the application.

Component instance is available on debug element as `debugElement.componentInstance`. As for directive instances and other providers, `debugElement.injector(SomeClass)` can be used to access them, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48687412/3731501).