# Simulate directive output in component unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5

My Angular 5 component uses [typeahead directive of ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead), like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="inputted"
   [typeahead]="days"
   (typeaheadOnSelect)="select($event)"
   class="form-control">
```

Now I want to test that my component does what is expected when the user selects an item in the typeahead. I need to simulate the typeahead directive's `typeaheadOnSelect` output. How can I access the directive in my unit test, to manually emit a `typeaheadOnSelect` event? This far I have come to this point:

```
const elem: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
```

which gives me the input element. How do I find the underlying typeahead directive from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685826/how-do-i-access-the-directive-instance-in-angular-from-console/48687412#48687412), directive instances can be retrieved from injector:

```
import { TypeaheadDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

...
const elem: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
const dir = elem.injector.get(TypeaheadDirective);
```

A proper way is to isolate unit tests from third-party units and provide stubs for ngx-bootstrap directives instead of importing its module. A stub can optionally expose its externals as local variables instead of using injector to get class instances:

```
let typeaheadOutput;

...
@Directive({ selector: '[typeahead]' }
class TypeaheadDirectiveMock {
  @Input() typeahead;
  @Output() typeaheadOnSelect = typeaheadOutput = new EventEmitter();
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [TypeaheadDirectiveMock], ...})
.compileComponents();
```