# Trigger router.navigate from console

Tags: angular, zone.js

I'm debugging an angular 7 app and i need to switch routes from the browser console. I was able to get into the Router service as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540653/get-access-to-angular-service-instance-from-javascript-code) however when i do

```
router.navigate(['customer']);
```

I get a warning  saying:

> Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call
>   'ngZone.run()'?

I've already tried to do the following but it didn't make any difference:

```
Zone.current.run(() => {
  router.navigate(['customer']);
});
```

Comment: Did you tried without "[]" ?